# un switch que recibe señal de un router puede dar señal a otros routers

Tags: redes, router

Mi idea es la siguiente, un router central con una direccion ip publica esta dando señal a una red conectada a un swich, este switch puede a su vez conectar otros routers y hacer que se comuniquen entre si?
algo asi, [image: ROUTER]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amigo estas demasiado confundido. Recuerda que el gateway es la puerta de enlace y¿ que es la puerta de enlace?, velo como el puerto de salida del router que esta conectado al switch. Es decir Sí tienes tres router con subredes distintas cada uno va a tener su propio gateway o salida. Yo me referia a que debes configurar dhcp para entregar direcciones Ip y eso lo haces en el router principal o en cada router por separado. No deberias tener problemas de comunicacion de ningun tipo si el switch esta por defecto. Al menos que hayas configurado Vlans.  Tu problema puede ser que no le estas configurando el enrutamiento. investiga RIP, EIGRP, OSPF y aplica el que mas te guste. tambien lo puedes hacer manual

Comment: Gracias ya pude entender los conceptos. Saludos!

Comment: de nada, cualquier duda avisame

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede. el switch dejará pasar por defecto todas las direcciones ip que entregues desde el router principal , previa configuracion de dhcp o manual. Ahora bien puedes configurar el switch en modo acceso(access) ó modo troncal(trunk). investiga esa parte.

Comment: No me quedo claro la parte de "que entregues desde el router principal", si mi gateway es 192.168.0.254 y mis subredes (otros router luego del swicht) 192.168.1.x y otro 192.168.2.x, le deberia asignar a esas subredes dicho gateway y ahi funcionaria la conexion?